# How to skip inside div on document click?

Tags: jquery

I want to close popup for any outside click of popup and want to keep popup as it is after click on popup.

I am using below function, But whenever i click any where it closes popup.
So how can i skip that popup div from below function.?

```
  $(document).on('click', function(e){

     $('#accountDetail').fadeOut(300);

   });
```

Comment: share relevant html code also.

Answer (score 1):

Try to check the `e.target` by using `.is()` whether it is the popping up element  or not,

```
$(document).on('click', function(e){
  if(!$(e.target).is('#accountDetail')){
    $('#accountDetail').fadeOut(300);
  }
});
```